# Why the date are different in single app for different devices?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am developing and iOS application and get date as integer value from the web service. I am converting the integer to date string using the following method.

```
func formatDate(timeInMiliSeconds: Int) -> String {

    let millse = timeInMiliSeconds

    let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:Double(millse) / 1000.0)

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy E"
    formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

    let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
    return dateString
}
```

When I run the application on iPhone 6S which runs iOS 9.3.4. It shows the date as `"01 Sep 2016 Thu"`. The iPhone 6S shows the intended date.

how ever when I build this app to iPad 2 which runs iOS 9.3.4. it shows the date as `"27 Dec 1969 Sat"`.

Anyone had this problem ? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the user language is different on the two devices, then the `local` object is different, hence the way the output string is generated.

Comment: What is the value of timeInMiliSeconds? Have you double-checked that it is the same on both devices?

Comment: @MartinR yes I have checked the timeInMiliSeconds. The value in the both devices are same but the date string is different in the devices.

Comment: @MartinR thank you for your comment. Finally figured out what the issue was. I was getting and converting the value as Int and in the 64 bit devices device was able to handle the value but in 32 bit devices the Int was small to hold the value. So I've updated the Int to uInt.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
formatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
```

to

```
formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()
```

Comment: I have updated as you mentioned but it gives the same result as before.

Comment: Could you check in setting your iPad2, General->Date & Time.
Set automatically - ON

Comment: It is on the iPad as you mentioned.